# How to get Google Speech Recognition Engine in an Android device

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-voice, google-voice-search

I have an Epson Moverio device, which is based on Android, but doesn't come with a speech recognition engine by default. I have successfully installed the Voice Search app and with that, I was able to use google voice recognition in the  app I am developing. Now, the problem is that app version I got is kind of old (I think its from 2011, since thats the last update for the Voice Search app ). Is there any other app similar to the Voice Search that I can install and will allow me to use the most recent Google's voice recognition engine?